# Unflattening view data to JSON with Mule DataMapper

Tags: json, mule, datamapper

I've got a database view that I need to send to a Web API call in JSON format, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get the datamapper to un-flatten the data. The format I want to get to is something like:

```
{
    "PersonId": "12345"
  , "CommonProp": "asdf"
  , "DataForPerson": [
        { "Prop1": "prop 1 value A", "Prop2": "prop 2 value A" }
      , { "Prop1": "prop 1 value B", "Prop2": "prop 2 value B" }
    ]
}
```

The format coming in from the view is something like:

```
PersonId    CommonProp    Prop1             Prop2
12345       asdf          prop 1 value A    prop 2 value A
12345       asdf          prop 2 value B    prop 2 value B
```

How can I go about doing this? The closest I've gotten is

```
{
    "PersonId": "12345"
  , "CommonProp": "asdf"
  , "DataForPerson": [
        { "Prop1": "prop 1 value A", "Prop2": "prop 2 value A" }
    ]
} {
    "PersonId": "12345"
  , "CommonProp": "asdf"
  , "DataForPerson": [
        { "Prop1": "prop 1 value B", "Prop2": "prop 2 value B" }
    ]
}
```

Obviously, this is not correct.  I'd tried to use the datamapper to do this, but didn't have any luck.

Thanks!

***edit*** Here's a picture of the flow:

[image: Mule Flow]

The poll and the JDBC are a `SELECT DISTINCT PERSON_ID FROM MY_VIEW`.  In the for each, I was hoping to make one JSON call per person.  I'm outputting to a file right now instead of invoking the Web API, though I did try the Web API call, and it works fine so long as it gets valid JSON.

Comment: Just to be clear: the data source type is CSV?

Comment: No, the data source is a SQL Server view.

Comment: So it's a `List<Map>` in Mule right?

Comment: I believe so (I know very little about Mule), though I had previously put an Object to JSON after the database.  Either way, same problem.

Comment: I've pasted what the flow looks like in Mule Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do realize that you've asked for a DataMapper solution. In case you want an alternate solution, the following uses MEL only:

```
<expression-component><![CDATA[
    payload =
      [
        'PersonId': payload[0].PersonId,
        'CommonProp': payload[0].CommonProp,
        'DataForPerson': (['Prop1': $.Prop1, 'Prop2': $.Prop2] in payload)
      ];
]]></expression-component>

<json:object-to-json-transformer />
```

Comment: This works, @David Dossot.  Do you think that there is no way to do this using a DataMapper?

Comment: It certainly possible to use DataMapper for this but I'm no expert with it: hopefully someone else will post a solution. Since you're an Enterprise Edition user you can also contact MuleSoft's professional support.