# Combining and sorting large Excel for CSV files

Tags: mule

Good afternoon!  I have a directory with a two identically-structured Excel files (I can also use CSV, and there might be in theory more than two) with about 50,000 rows each.  I need to combine all of the files in that directory, sort them by an ID, and then unflatten them for a call to a Web API.

In [an answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17434023/1102726), I saw how to unflatten data from a SQL query, so my question is this: how to I combine and then sort two large Excel (or CSV) files?  Thanks!

**edit**  I found http://blogs.mulesoft.org/using-in-memory-database-to-help-with-flat-file-integration/, which I'll be using for the sorting and combining.  My only remaining question is how I wait until all of the files have been loaded to continue with the flow?

Comment: We need to know a bit more about which OS, and which tools you'd be ready to use. CSV on linux would be very easy: `cat file1 file2 | sort`.

Comment: This will be running under Windows.  I'm hoping to use as little outside of Mule as possible.  I could use a PowerShell script to combine the files if there isn't a more Mule way of doing in.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm, can you take a look at the remaining portion of my question and let me know what you think?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a module at https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-requester that allows the use of a global endpoint or other source that would not normally be usable in the middle of a flow (e.g., an inbound file endpoint) in the middle of the flow.  If you use a global file endpoint, it will return a `NullPayload` if there is no file, otherwise it will return the first file.  I created a recursive flow that has a choice to see if the payload is null.  If it's not, it loads the file, puts it into Derby, and recurses.  If it is null, it continues doing whatever I want with the data.